# How to remove texts after a character?

Tags: c#, text, foreach

I have an array that holds user and passwords in user:pass form, and I like ro remove lines which pass is less than 8 characters or password uses repetitive chars like 111111,22222222222,...

I have tried string.take but it takes lines completely, I need conditional deletion.

```
public string[] lines;

//open file dialogue to load the user pass file

lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);

//delete button click event
//the place that I have problem
```

I have email:pass combination like so:
email1:1234567895121
email2:12345
email4:11111
email5"454545454545

and I would like the output to be like
email1:1234567895121
email5"454545454545

Comment: Can passwords contain the space character?

Comment: Is a password just numbers?

Comment: Just search every line for "11", "22", "33", ... "99". If you find any of those within a line, remove that lline from your array.

Comment: @mjwills it depends but mostly they don't

Comment: @HimBromBeere not it has characters too

Answer (score 0):

Just loop the characters of every line and see if the current is equal to the previous:

```
public string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName);
var filteredLines = new List<string>(lines);
foreach(var line in lines)
{
    var pair = line.Split(':');
    var mail = pair[0];
    var pass = pair[1]; // may throw exception on invalid format of your line
    for(int i = 1; i < pass.Length; i++)
    {
        if(pass[i] == pass[i - 1])
        {
            filteredLines.Remove(line);
            break;   // will break inner loop and continue on next line
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string[] lines =
{
    "email1:1234567895121",
    "email2:12345",
    "email3:22222222222",
    "email4:11111",
    "email5:454545454545"
};

lines = lines
    .Where(s =>
    {
        string pass = s.Split(new[] { ':' }, 2)[1];
        return pass.Length >= 8 && pass.Any(c => c != pass[0]);
    })
    .ToArray();

foreach (var s in lines)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

> email1:1234567895121
>   email5:454545454545